# Reach main viewport from controller

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5

I created a viewport in my launch function of application. Now in controller below, I am first destroying some window, and then I want to add my custom class to main viewport. Here is the code

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.login.LoginController', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewController',
    alias: 'controller.login',

    onLoginClick: function() {


        localStorage.setItem("TutorialLoggedIn", true);


        // Now, we are free to remove the login window.
        this.getView().destroy(); // this is Window class

         // ==========================================
         // *** Here I want to add main view to main viewport. How?
        Ext.create("MyApp.view.main.Main", {renderTo: /*How to get handle to main viewport?*/});

    }
});
```

I want to add `Main` view to viewport but **I can't get reference to main viewport**.

How can I achieve this?

---

This is how I created viewport in my launch:

```
 launch: function() { 

      //
      // Create viewport for the application
      //
      var myViewPort =  Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
            layout: 'fit',
            html: 'Main application',
            xtype:'viewport'
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my current solution. What is your opinion?

```
 onLoginClick: function() {


        localStorage.setItem("TutorialLoggedIn", true);


        // Now, we are free to remove the login window.
        this.getView().destroy();


        // Create main view
        var panel = Ext.create("MyApp.view.main.Main");
        globalVar.vp.add(panel);
     }
```

Where `globalVar.vp` is global object in `app.js` which holds reference to viewport.

Btw similarly above when I was creating `Main` and specifying `globalVar.vp` as `renderTo` parameter it was not working why?

---

Here is how the global is created

```
var globalVar = { vp : ""};


Ext.application({
         name: 'MyApp',
         appFolder:"app",

         // List views needed
         views: [
             'MyApp.view.login.Login',
             'MyApp.view.main.Main'
         ],

         requires: ["Ext.container.Viewport"],

         launch: function() { 

              //
              // Create viewport for the application
              //
              var myViewPort =  Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
                    layout: 'fit',
                    html: 'Main application',
              });

              // Store handle to viewport - to refer to it later from somewhere else
              globalVar.vp = myViewPort;
```

Comment: It explains why not to use `renderTo` in the docs: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2-classic/Ext.Component.html#cfg-renderTo

Answer (score 0):

you can give id to viewport created and use it to put main view inside viewport.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to access the view port then in the controller,

```
this.getView().up('viewport')
```

will return the reference to the viewport